# UseEffect not fetching data with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I want to do a query to my database when I first land on a results page. I want to fetch some data from the database and I provide an id on the front-end via axios like this.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Results = ({ linkURL, surveyId }) => {

    const linkToShare = linkURL;

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/get-questions/${surveyId}`);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Results page</h1>
        </>
    );
};

export default Results;
```

On the Back-End I am not getting any request and it doesn't show anything when refreshing on the page. At least I should be able to see the req.params.

```
app.get("/get-questions/:survey", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Route working", req.params);
});
```

I think it's not a problem with the params but with useEffect because I am not being able to make any connection with the server on this route. Tried several routes without params and nothing. Can't see anything logged on the console. Axios is working fine on other routes. Any idea what went wrong here?

EDIT

Inspecting the network tools I see this. The line above is a post request that works fine. The second one is my get to the server that's not working. Even if I am getting a 200.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The IP is missing because is a private IP? I don't see any reference to the base URL

Comment: You have to wait on the axios call. Add a `.then(...).catch()..`.

Comment: Are you running your app and server on the same port?  If not, you will need to proxy your requests to the server port.  You can do that in the package.json file

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1 The base URL is localhost:3000 and I want to fetch data from my server. This is already working with other axios requests.

Comment: @MjZac you are right, but first I should see some logs server-side, so the problem lies somewhere before sending the request to the server

Comment: @GlenCarpenter They are on different ports but it's already configured and works fine with other axios requests.

Comment: Ok, I think you should give us more debug info: open the page where you are calling Axios and inspect it. Among the tools available [Elements, Console, etc.] choose Console and see if any error is displayed. If not check in the Network tab if the request is correctly sent to the server. After checking these two elements we can make further considerations.

Comment: Actually, the component is mounting and logs everything in the browser's console. I edited the post with a couple of screenshots of the Network tab. Don't see anything strange. Even with code 200, I don't get anything logged in to the server.

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1 Sometimes it shows a 304 code. I am sure it has to be something with the configuration. But no idea what. I tried using pure axios and an instance for crsf. But nothing. The strange thing is that the post request works in another component smoothly.

Comment: Wait, if you got a 200 response code the client is calling the server correctly. Next step: try to send something in the response: then, always in network, when you click on the "Preview" you should see the body of your response. If the response is there, then you have to use a use state hook to set the state and generate your page

Comment: I posted you the "next steps" below, if you find some issues in between tell me and I will try to add further steps

Comment: After seeing the response I saw that I was getting my index.html in plain HTML as a response and everything was just the hoisting of the initialization of the server. I can't thank you enough @AndreaCostanzo1 for your help. You gave me some valuable debugging powers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at all the debug information you provided I can tell you that the request is performed correctly. The next step are:

1. Try to send something in the response: then, always in `Network`, when you click on the `Preview` you should see the body of your response.

*This is just an example:*

[image]

2. If you can see the response properly, the next step is just to update the UI:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Results = ({ linkURL, surveyId }) => {

    const linkToShare = linkURL;
    const [question,setQuestion] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/get-questions/${surveyId}`)
.then(res=>setQuestion(res.data.question)); //instead of .question use your JSON structure
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{`Question ${surveyId}:`}</h1>
            <p>{question}</p>
        </>
    );
};

export default Results;
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an axios instance?

If not, you can do this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
```

import and use likes this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { api } from 'instace directory';

const Results = ({ linkURL, surveyId }) => {

    const linkToShare = linkURL;

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get(`/get-questions/${surveyId}`);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Results page</h1>
        </>
    );
};

export default Results;
```

Comment: I tried already with an instance and didn't work either